# how to use foldLeft to flatten a DataFrame having json string as one of the column and having only user selected columns from json string in output

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am creating a utility function which would take column names to be fetched from json string object and base DataFrame (also Having that Json string column) object. The output DataFrame would retain all columns from base df except the json string col, instead i would need flattened columns from json string which I gave as input.

My input DataFrame:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- order_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- barcode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- metadata: string (nullable = true)
```

the metadata is
`{"scan_count":"1","uom":"Kg","uom_value":"1.002","sku_name":"Chicken Breast Small", "quantity":"1","product_id": "pr_as7k1"}`

Expected DataFrame:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- order_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- barcode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- uom: string (nullable = true)
 |-- uom_value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_id: string (nullable = true)
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def  expandJsonStringCols(cols: Seq[String])(df: DataFrame): DataFrame={
     cols.foldLeft(df)((df, nxtCol) => df.withColumn(nxtCol, get_json_object(col("metadata"), "$.${nxtCol}")))
}
df.transform(expandJsonStringCols( Seq("uom", "uom_value", "product_id"))) show
```

**But all new columns are NULL.**

Comment: sample data to test
```val jsonString="""{"scan_count":"1","uom":"Kg","uom_value":"1.002","sku_name":"Chicken Breast Small", "quantity":"1","product_id": "pr_as7k1"}""";

val data = Seq((1,"lsj9mvdaw7me","7003450", jsonString));
import spark.implicits._

val df=data.toDF("id","order_id","barcode","metadata");
df.show(false)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!

Turning

```scala
cols.foldLeft(df)((df, nxtCol) => df.withColumn(nxtCol, get_json_object(col("metadata"), "$.${nxtCol}")))
```

into

```scala
cols.foldLeft(df)((df, nxtCol) => df.withColumn(nxtCol, get_json_object(col("metadata"), "$." + nxtCol)))
```

fixes your issue. Basically, your string expansion of `"$.${nxtCol}"` was not working.

This is the final working code:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val jsonString="""{"scan_count":"1","uom":"Kg","uom_value":"1.002","sku_name":"Chicken Breast Small", "quantity":"1","product_id": "pr_as7k1"}"""
val data = Seq((1,"lsj9mvdaw7me","7003450", jsonString))
val df=data.toDF("id","order_id","barcode","metadata")

def expandJsonStringCols(cols: Seq[String])(df: DataFrame): DataFrame={
  cols.foldLeft(df)((df, nxtCol) => df.withColumn(nxtCol, get_json_object(col("metadata"), "$." + nxtCol)))
}

df.transform(expandJsonStringCols( Seq("uom", "uom_value", "product_id"))) show
+---+------------+-------+--------------------+---+---------+----------+
| id|    order_id|barcode|            metadata|uom|uom_value|product_id|
+---+------------+-------+--------------------+---+---------+----------+
|  1|lsj9mvdaw7me|7003450|{"scan_count":"1"...| Kg|    1.002|  pr_as7k1|
+---+------------+-------+--------------------+---+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Koedlt  !! , i knew something was wrong while accessing the variable inside lambda